# Print small and capital alphabets in interleaved manner

Tags: multithreading

I have two character array of alphabets. One is of small letters and other is of capital letter as shown below.

```
char arr1[] = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz";
char arr2[] = "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ";
```

I want to run two threads(POSIX) to get the output as below.

```
aAbBcCdDeEfFgGhHiIjJkKlLmMnNoOpPqQrRsStTuUvVwWxXyYzZ.
```

Comment: Threads run independently and hence they don't provide a guarantee of order of the characters while printing. But I'm curious why do you even need this? There are other ways of joining two arrays into one so that they have such interleaving.

Comment: Can you show us what code you already have and maybe tell us which programming language (and OS) you are using? (I assume C on linux).